# Issue in creating Pager with Tablayout

Tags: android, android-studio

**MainActivity.Java**

Here is my Code which causes the crash on launching the application.. It only runs once I comment the code of `OnCreate()`

**OnCreate Method**

```
final TabLayout tb = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(new FragmentManagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),MainActivity.this));
tb.setupWithViewPager(pager);
```

**Log of my project**

```
12-12 13:15:42.800 30536-30536/pk.com.messenger.rabta.tablayout E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 13:15:42.800 30536-30536/pk.com.messenger.rabta.tablayout E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
12-12 13:15:42.800 30536-30536/pk.com.messenger.rabta.tablayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at pk.com.messenger.rabta.tablayout.FragmentManager.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:38)
12-12 13:15:42.800 30536-30536/pk.com.messenger.rabta.tablayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
12-12 13:15:42.800 30536-30536/pk.com.messenger.rabta.tablayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
12-12 13:15:42.800 30536-30536/pk.com.messenger.rabta.tablayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
12-12 13:15:42.800 30536-30536/pk.com.messenger.rabta.tablayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
12-12 13:15:42.800 30536-30536/pk.com.messenger.rabta.tablayout E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
```

**FragmentLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
              android:text="Large Text"
              android:id="@+id/textView1"
              android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow.. Would you mind elaborating your comment..

Comment: When you get a crash, you will get the reason in log cat window. Copy that and paste it along with your question.

Comment: Check out the log file.

Comment: Can you post the fragment code and its corresponding layout, problem is in fragment code

Comment: Post complete code. The log cat says you are casting textview with linear layout.

Comment: Yes, in your layout  you are performing this TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourlinearlayout) ,   just check it out

Comment: In fragmentManager i am using this..

TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        textView.setText("Fragment #"+mPage);

Comment: Fragment Layout file Added..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you fragment do this,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourFragment, container, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText("Success");
    return view;
}
```

Comment below for further information.

Comment: OnCreateView is not allowing me to use

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

Instead i am using

TextView textView = (TextView) view;

Comment: Can you post your fragment code, i will correct it.

Comment: TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);   add this line

Comment: I have added this line..


TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1)

and now its working..